# Verificação de Arquivos PHP/FTP

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while, ftp

Olá,

Estou com a seguinte situação:

Minha empresa deseja validar todos os arquivos de uma determinada pasta no FTP com o BD (MySQL), para ter certeza que todos estão sendo utilizados e os que não estiverem sejam excluídos.

O Problema:

A tabela do banco possui + de 1 milhão de registros.

---

Consegui pegar a lista dos nomes dos arquivos no FTP e consigo pegar a lista de registro no BD, porém não consigo comparar e gerar um resultado.

Codigo da Lista:

```
foreach($contents as $file){
    echo $file;
};
```

Codigo no Banco:

```
$loadImg = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM imagem_imovel');
while($checkImg = mysql_fetch_assoc($loadImg)){
    echo $checkImg['imaNome'];
};
```

Como comparar esses dois para saber se o nome do arquivo do FTP possui algum registro no BD sem fazer uma consulta a cada nome ?

Comment: Isso é algo que será executado diariamente? Se não então não tem problema demorar, se sim, você precisa realmente fazer isso da forma mais rápida possível? Se não, você já sabe, se sim, então provavelmente não deveria fazer `SELECT * FROM ...`

Comment: Será executado apenas uma vez, porém sempre acontece o erro 503.

Answer (score 1):

Para comparar os arquivos com o seu banco de dados, podemos colocar o nome dos arquivos e o nome das imagens do seu BD em dois arrays. Assim, somente chamaremos o banco uma vez.

O código abaixo grava o nome dos arquivos **com o path completo** em um array $files, salva o nome das imagens (verificar se estão com o path) no array $images e verifica se cada arquivo existe no BD, imprimindo na tela os que não existirem.

Se realmente for deletar os arquivos, faça um backup do diretório, verifique se o php tem permissões para apagar estes arquivos e descomente as últimas linhas do código.

```
<?php

    // Encontra nomes dos arquivos de determinada pasta e salva no array $files
    $files = glob("/path/to/directory/*.{jpg,gif,png}", GLOB_BRACE);

    // Busca nome das imagens no seu Banco de Dados (a conexão já deve estar estabelecida)
    $loadImg = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM imagem_imovel');
    while($checkImg = mysql_fetch_assoc($loadImg)){
        $images[] = $checkImg['imaNome'];
        // ATENÇÃO, SE AS IMAGENS NO BD NÃO ESTIVEREM COM O MESMO PATH DOS ARQUIVOS, COMENTE A LINHA ACIMA E DESCOMENTE A SEGUINTE:
        //$images[] = '/path/to/directory/' . $checkImg['imaNome'];

    };

    //verifica se o nome de arquivo existe no Banco de Dados. Se não existir, imprime na tela
    foreach($files as $file){
        if(!in_array($file, $images)){
            // imprime no console (\n para pular linha). Se for para imprimir no html use <br>
            echo $file . "\n";
            // Se quiser realmente deletar os arquivos, descomente o código abaixo:
            //if (file_exists($file))
            //  unlink($file);

        }
    }
?>
```